# Find limit of sequence with a series in the numerator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck on this limit problem:

Caculate the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2+5^2+9^2+...+(4n-3)^2}{n^3}$$

I am not sure what to do about the sum in the numerator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Observe that, for $k=1,2,3,\cdots$, we have
$$
3\cdot(4k-3)^2=\left[16k^3-12k^2-k \right]-\left[16(k-1)^3-12(k-1)^2-(k-1) \right]
$$ the right hand side then leads to a [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).

Comment: How did you create the right side of the equation?

Comment: @OlivierOloa The OP's right - it would be a lot more helpful to him if you showed how you arrived at that conclusion, rather than just pulling it out of a hat.

Comment: Perhaps since $(n\pm 1)^3=n^3\pm 3n^2+3n\pm1$, $(n+1)^3-(n-1)^3=6n^2+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formulae
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2};\quad  \sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.\tag{1}
$$
to get that
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (4i-3)^2
&=16\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-24\sum_{i=1}^ni+\sum_{i=1}^n9\\
&=16\times \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-24\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+9n\tag{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
When computing the limit, we are only interested in the term of highest degree in (2), namely $\dfrac{16(2)}{6}n^3=\dfrac{16}{3}n^3$. More precisely,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (4i-3)^2\sim\frac{16}{3}n^3\implies 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (4i-3)^2}{n^3}
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ (16/3)n^3}{n^3}
=16/3.\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By Stolz Cesaro
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2+5^2+9^2+...+(4n-3)^2}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(4n+1)^2}{(n+1)^3-n^3}$$

SC is very useful in limits of ratios where one or both of the denominator/numerator are sums.